# How to use a defined method in another method

Tags: ruby, methods

I'm wondering if you can use a defined method into another defined method

like for example

```
def method1(example)

    funtion1

end

def method2(example)

    funtion2

end
```

Like how can you use method1 to method2

Comment: Could you refactor your question a little bit, it is very unclear what you are asking for here. Do you mean how to pass a method as an argument or how to call one method from within the second method?

Comment: Yes exactly, thanks @BroiSatse. Sorry I'm a little bit unfamiliar on how to express on other arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def method_1(arg)
  arg.call
end

def method_2
  puts 'hi'
end

method_1(method(:method_2)) #=> should print 'hi'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't pass a method to a method. However you can pass a proc to a method.

Define a [proc](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/Proc.html) like so

```
proc = Proc.new {|x| puts x}
```